# groups command is working but groups <username> is not, inside a docker container. What's the reason?

Tags: linux, docker, ldap

Inside a docker container, if I type `groups` it works and gives 'root' in the result but when I type `groups <username>` it says `groups: '<username>': no such user.` What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Command `groups` without supplying user argument  returns the groups to which the current user belongs. In your case the `root` group. It appears that the username you supplied in call with `username` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. where is the <username> supposed to exist for the docker container to recognize and not give that error?

Comment: The command `users` returns the list of available users in your system.

Comment: from my dev system, i am able to run groups <teammate'sldap> and get the results. And when i ran 'users' on that system it resulted just my name. so how do i get similar behavior on my docker instance? i need to be able to run groups <anyldapname> and get the results. Thanks!

Comment: Does your container have LDAP configured?

Comment: i don't think it is LDAP configured. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: It is unclear to me yet how your host is configured for LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

To get your locally configured groups (and users) into the container, you would mount `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/groups` into it.

In your case there is LDAP involved. You should add information how it is integrated on your host. You could have a look if your LDAP integration syncs into the `/etc/groups` and `/etc/passwd` files on your host.